# removing dynamically created divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im working on a scratchcard game for school. It has to be fully coded in Javascript. The thing is, I can't get the removing of divs right.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js/skeleton.js"></script>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Scratch Cards - Match three the same</h1>
   <div id="kraslot">
     <img src=""  class="kraslotimage1" id="kraslotimage1">
     <img src=""  class="kraslotimage2">
     <img src=""  class="kraslotimage3">
     <button id="button">Again</button>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
/* Copyleft 2013, all wrongs reversed */
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*globals console*/

(function () {
'use strict';


// Hier onder jouw code
// ------------------------------
// This script must be within the relatively positioned DIV.


    var kraslot=new Array('image/peer.jpg','image/kiwi.jpg','image/banaan.jpg');

    var zetBlokjesNeer = function () {

        var idn = 1;
        var blokje,p,j,k;


        // voor elke afbeelding teller p
        for (p=0;p<1;p++)
        // voor elke rij, teller j
        for (j=0;j<4;j++)
        // voor elke kolom, teller k
        for (k=0;k<4;k++) {
            console.log(idn);
            blokje = document.createElement("div");
            blokje.id = "M"+idn;
            blokje.classList.add("blokje");
            // HIER GAAT NOG IETS MIS
            blokje.style.top = eval(0+j*25) + 'px';
            blokje.style.left = eval(130+k*25) + 'px';
            document.getElementById("kraslot").appendChild(blokje);
            blokje.addEventListener("click", krassen)
            // hier nog een blokje.addEventListener toevoegen die luistert naar click en de functie krassen aanroept

            var krassen = function(){
            document.getElementById(blokje);
            blokje.remove();
            }
            idn++;
        }


        // document.write('<DIV ID="M'+idn+'" 
        // onmouseover="style.display=\'none\'" 
        // CLASS="general'+i+'" 
        // STYLE="position:absolute;width:25;height:25;top:'+eval(0+j*25)+';left:'+eval(125+p*125+k*25)+'"
        // ></DIV>');
        // }
    }



    var rnd = function () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*kraslot.length);
    }

    function scimgload() {
        document.images[0].src=kraslot[rnd()];
        document.images[1].src=kraslot[rnd()];
        document.images[2].src=kraslot[rnd()];
    }

    var refresh = function(){
        refresh = document.createElement ("div");
        refresh.id = refresh;
        refresh.addEventListener("click", reload)
    }

    var reload = function(){
        location.reload(true);
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        scimgload();
        zetBlokjesNeer();

    }    


    // function scmetal() {
    // for (i=0;i<192;i++)
    // document.all['M'+i].style.display="";
    // }
// ------------------------------

// Sluiten van de scope functie
}());
       // TODO bedenk hoe je de transparantie van event.target kan verranderen
        // gebruik bijvoorbeeld classList
```

As you can see, the blocks called "blokjes" are created by a for loop.

The function "krassen" is supposed to be able to remove every "blokje" on click. 
For some reason it only removes the last "blokje" right now.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: can you put it in a fiddle?

Comment: Why are the comments in some foreign language? Have you copied this code from someone?

Comment: I don't think addEventListeners works in IE < 9, you have to use attachEvent for them.

Comment: This foreign language is my native language, someone else worked on this project before I Did. That's why.

Comment: Here is the fiddle you asked for Oliver. http://jsfiddle.net/G88Zb/

Comment: Ok. Problem No. 1: You are defining the event handler function after binding the click event listener. This will definitely not behave as you expect. Fix that first.

Comment: Like This?     `var krassen = function(){
                document.getElementById(blokje.idn);
                blokje.remove();
                }
                
                document.getElementById("kraslot").appendChild(blokje);
                blokje.addEventListener("click", krassen)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
blokje.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var target = e.target;
    if (target.parentElement) {
         target.parentElement.removeChild(target);
    }
});
```

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qbv6C/

EDIT:

Add this function definition somewhere:

```
var clickHandler = function(e){
        var target = e.target;
        if (target.parentElement) {
             target.parentElement.removeChild(target);
        }
}
```

Remove:

```
blokje.addEventListener("click", krassen)
            // hier nog een blokje.addEventListener toevoegen die luistert naar click en de functie krassen aanroept

            var krassen = function(){
            document.getElementById(blokje);
            blokje.remove();
            }
```

Add:

```
blokje.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
```

Comment: But, as I said above... if you are using IE < 9, addEventListener needs to be attachEvent... I'll leave that for you to deal with.

Comment: The Thing is, The divs are dynamically created by for loops and aren't predefined in the HTML.

Comment: Well... that absolutely doesn't matter. The fiddle was to prove my answer... it's up to YOU to implement it. You would want to create a function out of mine and attach IT to your "programatically-created div"

Comment: So the .removeChild() should be "M"+idn? Because that's the name the 16 generated ID's are given.

Comment: You're welcome... however... don't forget about the IE < 9 issue... I'll leave that up to you to figure out...

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(blokje);
```

is not the right id..

maybe try:

```
 document.getElementById(blokje.id);
```

Comment: It's still only deleting the latest created "blokje" after I tried this code.